# Spark: difference of semantics between reduce and reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, reduce

In Spark's documentation, it says that RDDs method [`reduce`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) requires a associative AND commutative binary function.

However, the method [`reduceByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) ONLY requires an associative binary function.

```
sc.textFile("file4kB", 4)
```

I did some tests, and apparently it's the behavior I get. Why this difference? Why does `reduceByKey` ensure the binary function is always applied in certain order (to accommodate for the lack of commutativity) when `reduce` does not?

Example, if a load some (small) text with 4 partitions (minimum):

```
val r = sc.textFile("file4k", 4)
```

then:

```
r.reduce(_ + _)
```

returns a string where parts are not always in the same order, whereas:

```
r.map(x => (1,x)).reduceByKey(_ + _).first
```

always returns the same string (where everything is in the same order than in the original file).

(I checked with `r.glom` and the file content is indeed spread over 4 partitions, there is no empty partition).

Comment: I guess the idea with `reduceByKey` is that you probably have a lot of different keys so it is okay to reduce everything for a single key on a single thread, which means you can always run the computation left-to-right.  In contrast, `reduce` will often be used on a large data set so must not care about order of operations.

Comment: How many executors are you using in your experiments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I am concerned this is an error in the documentation and results you see are simply incidental. Practice, [other resources](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/data-exploration-using-spark.html) and a simple [analysis of the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b122c861cd72b580334a7532f0a52c0439552bdf/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L72) show that function passed to `reduceByKey` should be not only associative but commutative as well.

- practice - while it looks like the order is preserved in a local mode it is no longer true when you run Spark on a cluster, including standalone mode.
- other resources - to quote [Data Exploration Using Spark](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/data-exploration-using-spark.html) from [AmpCamp 3](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/index.html):

  > There is a convenient method called reduceByKey in Spark for exactly this pattern. Note that the second argument to reduceByKey determines the number of reducers to use. By default, Spark assumes that the reduce function is commutative and associative and applies combiners on the mapper side.
- code - `reduceByKey` is implemented using `combineByKeyWithClassTag` and creates `ShuffledRDD`. Since Spark doesn't guarantee the order after shuffling the only way to restore it would be to attach some metadata to the partially reduced records. As far as I can tell nothing like this takes place.

On a side note `reduce` as it is implemented in PySpark will work just fine with a function which is only commutative. It is of course just a detail of an implementation and not a part of the contract.

Comment: I'd add that reduce is an action, returning data to driver, while reduceByKey is a transformation, returning another RDD

Comment: Thanks! But then, is there some way in Spark to ensure the correctness of a NON-commutative treatment? Or is it beyond the scope of Spark?

Comment: I am not sure if understand the question. Do you ask if it is possible to automatically test / prove commutativity or simply want to use non-commutative function with `reduce`? If this is the second case mimicking PySpark behavior (`mapPartitions(reduceFunc)` => `collect` => reduce(reduceFunc)`) should work with some performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You mean PySpark's reduce has an ordered behaviour? Why this difference?

Comment: Side-question: it seems you're resorting on `collect` returning an array with the partitions in the original order. That's a behaviour I observed too, but it isn't documented. Is it a reliable behaviour?

Comment: Given the current code base it is and it is unlikely to change. There are different pieces of Spark code which depend on this behavior. Regarding difference in PySpark behavior I am not dev but my bet is that is simply a matter of tools. Python until 3.4 - 3.5 doesn't provide decent async primitives. Moreover there is not much to gain if reduce function is not very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code documentation, recently updated/corrected. (thanks @zero323) :

> `reduceByKey` merges the values for each key using an associative and commutative reduce function. This will also perform the merging locally on each mapper before sending results to a reducer, similarly to a "combiner" in MapReduce.

So it was in fact actually a documentation error like @zero323 pointed out in his answer.

You can check the following links to the code to make sure :

- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L304
- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L1560